# Package android.media.tv.tuner is not found in android.jar file

Tags: android-studio, sdk, android-tv, android-sdk-manager, android-soong

From [this documentation](https://source.android.com/docs/devices/tv/tuner-framework) We can see many "android.media.tv.tuner" package reference.

From the SDK source code provided by SDK Manager (in AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-30\android for example), this package is indeed present.

But from the android.jar in my Android Studio project, There is no reference to this package at all.

Why this module is not built by default ?

How can I create/configure an android TV project with this tuner module ?

To get around this problem, I try to build myself the android.jar file, but the soong_build command fails :

```
$ soong_build -b out/soong -l Android.bp -o Android.ninja Android.bp
panic: Found two Blueprint files in directory . :  Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project and .
```

Answer (score 0):

All components inside "android.media.tv.tuner" package are tagged as @SystemAPI or @Hides. So these cannot be visible from SDK.